# What is AMD Bulldozer?

Tags: motherboard, amd-phenom

I am in need of replacing my motherboard and processor, and was looking at getting the AMD Phenom II x6.  Then I started seeing posts about AMD's bulldozer project.  What is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulldozer platform will run on AMDs new AM3+ socket. There are a few motherboards available now the will take your current processor (assuming you're running a relatively current AMD rig) and a replacement Bulldozer processor when they get to market in August. Or, if you need the performance now, you could go with Sandy Bridge.